# Managing memory in data intensive operations in Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, memory-management, large-files

I'm parsing very large XML files (sizes vary from 50Mb upto 1Gb) using [cElementTree](http://effbot.org/zone/celementtree.htm) in Python. Let us consider the following sample xml file:

```
 <rootTag>
   <innerTag>...</innerTag>
   <innerTag>...</innerTag>
   <!-- repeat a large number of times -->
   <innerTag>...</innerTag>
 </rootTag>
```

cElementTree allows me to parse innerTag iteratively. Thus, I can clear after parsing through one innerTag, I can clear it from the memory to make way for the new innerTag.

So far so good.

For my parsing, I'm supposed to identify certain innerTags of interest and subsequently store some of the containing information into a python list.

```
resultList = []

#Logic for each innerTag
if condition == True:
  resultList.append(usefulInfo) #some object
```

The problem here is that since the list is kept in memory, it depletes as more objects are appended.

I was advised to use *del* for all temporary variables I used while parsing and have already done that. I do not understand however how I can *del* the list *temporarily* only to be loaded in memory later when I iterate through the list.

Any help is highly appreciated. Let me know if any additional information is required.

Comment: You won't want to delete elements from your list. Often, I have used shelve to construct a dictionary-like object in these circumstances (even with files over a Gb), but I'm guessing you would prefer to drop the objects straight into a list.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Does shelve have some sort of in built memory management system? While I would indeed prefer using a list, a hack could be to create a shelve with 1,2,3,... as keys and objects as values.

Comment: If the interesting innerTag contents are too bulky to keep in memory, you may have to write them to disk until you are done processing the xml.  Then iterate through the saved interesting innerTag elements.  You might keep a list of innerTag element ids in memory as you go.  ... Well I just looked up shelve and I guess that's what it does.

Comment: @BrendaJ.Butler That indeed was the fail safe I thought of. I was wondering if Python offers any such feature as part of the language - one which interfaces with the disk to store data temporarily.